# Java Selenium Testng - Factory not working on Windows

Tags: java, selenium, testng, testng-dataprovider

I set up a project using Intellij on Linux using Selenium and Testng using the factory method with dataProviders. On Linux the process runs as the following:

```
**Data 1:**
initialize
second
AfterTest
**Data 2**
initialize
second
AfterTest
```

But when I transferred the project onto a Windows machine, installed all of the libraries (still using intellij) I get the following output:

```
Initialize
Initialize(1)
second
second (1)
AfterTest
```

I'm not too sure why I'm getting differences since it's the same code. Please see the code below:

```
   @DataProvider(name = "data")
   public static Object[][] data() {
      // This is where I get the data from

   }
   @Factory(dataProvider = "data")
   public TestSuite1(Data data)
   {
       super();
       this.data = data; 
   }

   @Test(priority = 1, description = "First test")
   public void initialize()
   {
       System.out.println("DO THIS FIRST");
   }

   @Test(priority = 2, description = "Do this after")
   public void second()
   {
       System.out.println("DO THIS AFTER");
   }

   @AfterClass
   public void AfterTest() throws InterruptedException
   {
       System.out.println("I HAVE FINISHED THE TEST");
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see here :https://howtodoinjava.com/testng/testng-factory-annotation-tutorial/ That "@Factory" must be used with "@DataProvider" to test ...

I didn't see "@DataProvider" in your code ... and it seem to not use a correct form of code for TestNG...

That could be why there is a difference ...

Comment: I have updated my question - Please see! I do have the data provider. It works correctly on my linux box just not on a windows machine

Answer (score 0):

You have to check your testNg xml file as well. since I cannot see your any test steps use data from data provider. Your second script is similar to parallel test execution. please make sure your suite details like below.

```
<suite name="Suite" parallel="false" thread-count="0" verbose="2">
<test name="TestName"> <!--Do not add any other unless its necessary-->
        <classes>
            <class name="className"/>
        </classes>
 </test>
```